# Is there a way of showing an approximate value in Sage?

Tags: sage, approximate

This is probably a silly question, but I used Sage to solve a system of linear equations, and I got exact solutions, which involve a lot of linear combinations of e^a (a is a constant). I know Sage is for symbolic expressions, but in this particular case I honestly just want some Real values.

Is there a simple way to tell Sage to approximate these answers? Like a way to force converting e^a into a floating  point number?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`N` function](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/functional.html) or [`numerical_approx` function](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/functional.html#sage.misc.functional.numerical_approx) or `numerical_approx` method (they're aliases for each other) to get a decimal from an exact value.

```py
sage: x = sqrt(2)
sage: x
sqrt(2)
sage: x.n()
1.41421356237310
```